# Automator Action/Bash Script for selecting files from a list

Tags: finder, automator, bash

As a part of my workflow, I often face this scenario:

- I have a folder with let's say, 100 files named 1.mov to 100.mov
- I have a list of **valid files** let's say, files 1.mov, 2.mov .... 15.mov (These names can be random)

Now I want finder to separate the valid files from the heap of original files by either marking them or creating a new folder and copying them recursively.

How can I achieve this with automator?

Answer (score 1):

Given a text file, **filelist.txt**, containing the files enumerated, one per line, the following command will move those files (and only those files) found in the current directory and beneath it, to a directory, **destination**, located in the user's Documents folder:

```
xargs -J % find . -name % -exec mv {} ~/Documents/destination/ \; < filelist.txt
```

*xargs*: accepts the files listed coming from stdin (or in this case, filelist.txt), replacing their path into the % variable in the following *find* command

*find*: locates those files if they exist, then **exec**utes the following command on each file

*mv*: moves the found file, represented by {}, to the destination

Incorporating this line into an Automator workflow is left to the reader.